# How to capture input when debbuging in Visual Studio Code with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code for Linux and I've created simple console application in .NET Core using C# with OmniSharp, which gets a user input. The problem is, that when I debug the application it stops on getting the user input and cannot go forward. It cannot receive the input. There is no error it just doesn't receive the input. The program is waiting endless.

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string input = Console.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine("In debug mode you will not see this message... As far as you are using VS code");
}
```

Comment: did you try to write the input to console ? I mean Console.WriteLine(input);
and I think you have to write Console.ReadKey(); to deny application from exit until a key pressed( I don't program on linux ) but the same thing must be done on windows